# Autoincrementing table in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, laravel, phpmyadmin

I want to auto_increment an existing table in phpmyadmin. The table consists of the following columns. Id,gallery_id,image,created_at,updated_at. Now, I want to auto_increment the column gallery_id but when running the following command, 'ALTER TABLE gallery_images MODIFY gallery_id bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY_KEY' it show me an error 'Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key'. How can I get rid of this error and auto_increment the column gallery_id on the table called gallery_images. I just want to auto_increment the single column.

Answer (score 0):

Primary_key should not be underbarred

correct syntax is

```
ALTER TABLE gallery_images MODIFY gallery_id bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY;
```

NB not null is unnecessary.